# Laravel 5.4. Return a controller's action in middleware

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, middleware

I use middleware directly to the route:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}', 'Site\PageController@showPage')->middleware('static_pages');
```

I try to return the controller's action in middleware in a such way:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $slug = $request->route('slug');

    //list of non-static pages
    if(!in_array($slug, ['about', 'contacts', 'blog', '']))
    {
        return action('Site\PageController@showPage', ['page_name' => $slug]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But I've got an error when the middleware had worked:

ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156:
Trying to get property of non-object

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you redirecting to this route through a form?

Comment: The most interesting thing is no) I use this middleware directly to the route. I have added code to my question.